# pyinstaller 5.0.1 How to add updateable config.json to .exe (--onefile)

Tags: python, json, pyinstaller

I am compiling a program into a single .exe where there is a config.json file. It contains settings that can change during the course of the program and must be saved so that the next time you run the .exe, the already changed settings from the config.json file are used.

Compiled as follows: pyinstaller -F --add-data "config.json;." main_worker.py

The program works, but changes in config.json are not saved (

I understand that when compiling into one .exe, all added data files are unloaded somewhere into temporary files and are deleted after the .exe is closed.

But is there any way to save the changes or overwrite the config.json file which is inside the .exe ?

Comment: you should save file in user's folder. And later read also from user's folder. So when you start program then you could check if there is this file in user's folder and read it - and if it doesn't have it then copy to user's folder file which was uncompressed from .exe (so you treat file in exe as version with default values at start). on Linux you can use `os.path.expanduser('~')` to get user's folder - but maybe on Windows it will also work.

Comment: I know, but i use uuid to prevent multiusing of my .exe. And how to ptotect them from user changing in this case? I need to create .exe, which after first starting, can be start only on this user's pc

Comment: you can't protect it.

Comment: what a pity, thx for ur answer